# Spring MVC - Create dependent dropdown based on DB entities

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

everyone.
I have two dropdowns: one of them is populated by a list of States and the other should by populated by cities.
Here are the models:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "state")
public class State {

    /Id and others attributes
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "state")
    private List<City> cities;
    
    /getters and setters
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "city")
public class City {

    /Id and others attributes

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "state_id")
    private State state;

    /Getters and setters
```

Now the controller:

```
@GetMapping("/new")
    public ModelAndView newDistrict() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(CRUD_VIEW);
        modelAndView.addObject(new District());
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("AllStates")
    public List<State> AllStates(){
        return stateRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    @ModelAttribute("AllCities")
    public List<City> AllCities(){
        return cityRepository.findAll();
    }
```

And this is the view:

```
<form action="/discricts" th:object="${discrict}" method="post">
        <input type = "hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
        <select name="state" class="list-states" >
            <option th:each="state : ${AllStates}" th:value="${state.id}" th:text="${state}" 
             th:field = "*{state}">
            </option>
        </select>
        
        <select name="city" class="list-cities">
            <option th:each="city : ${AllCities}" th:value="${city.id}" 
             th:text="${city.cities}" th:field = "*{city}">
            </option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
```

So I want the second dropdown to show only the cities the state selected on the first dropdown contains, but it shows all the registered cities. Is there any way I can do that? I'm really new to Spring and MVC, by the way. Any help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that with Thymeleaf alone since you want this is done on select (so without reloading the page) it has to be done via JS.

```
function ajax_get(url, callback) {
    let selectedCountry = document.getElementById("select1").value;
    fetch(url + "/" + selectedCountry)
      .then(response => {
          processData(response)
      });
}

function processData(data) {
    let options = document.getElementById("select2").children;
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        let content = options[i].textContent;
        if(!data.includes(content)) {
            options[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

so here i am getting children of the second second select using an id of "select2" so obviously you need to set an id to your select and adjust it accordingly

Also you need to add an event listener so that on each selection of the select1 the ajax call gets called:

```
document.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("select1").onselect(ajax_get("your_endpoint", processData))
}
```

ps: i didnt test the ajax call, so some minor adjustment might be needed, in general this is the approach your problem requires. The endpoint needs to accept country as path variable and return a list of strings (cities)

also don't forget to define an endpoint

Comment: It worked just fine, thank you very much!